# jQuery click event is not working How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-close closelabel" data-input="pettype" data-value="Lost" style="font-size: 16px; padding-left: 3px;cursor:pointer"></i>
```

jQuery:

```
$("fa.fa-close.closelabel").click(function(){
    alert("hello world");
});
```

1. jQuery click function is inside of document ready function.
2. HTML is coming dynamically by using another jQuery function. That function is outside of document ready function.

anyone can please help me why this function is not working?

Comment: $(document).on('click','fa.fa-close.closelabel',(function(){
    alert("hello world");
});

Answer (score 0):

use $(document).on for dynamic content .

```
  $(document).on('click','.fa.fa-close.closelabel',function(){ alert("hello world"); });
```

note : typo class name missed first dot

Comment: place this code inside or outside of document ready function?

Answer (score 0):

There exists no element `$("fa.fa-close.closelabel")` Your selector is attempting to find an element with the tagname `fa` and classes `fa-close` and `closelabel`

Change to

```
$("i.fa.fa-close.closelabel").click(function(){
    alert("hello world");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the first dot

```
$(".fa.fa-close.closelabel").click(function(){ alert("hello world"); });
```